# MacBook Pro 15" CPU Overheat

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook pro 15" 2010 temperature gets over 150 c. Is this normal? I have attached an image for sensors temperature. I recently faced automatic restarts, is this related to temperature?

[image]

Comment: Hmm - the ambient temperature of 88 isn't likely C - are you sure you have your temperature units correct? Everything looks perfectly normal if you are displaying °F and not °C - nothing makes sense if you are displaying °C unless you are working in an oven/kiln situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sensor temperatures probably show °Fahrenheit instead of °Celsius.

Open iStatMenus -> Sensors and change the Degrees from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

The Palm Rest will show ~30°C instead of 85°F (mine - a similar MBP - has 31°C), the CPU Die will show 54°C  instead of 129°F (mine has ~63°C)...